# Php HTML email check on iphone and tablet

Tags: iphone, html-email

I created a nice html email using php. I already check the template on gmail,yahoo and outlook. Do I still need to check it on iphone and tablet even it perfectly working on gmail, yahoo and outlook?

Comment: I don't iphone and tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine for the most part.

Android tablets:
Make sure your biggest table has the `max-width` css inline and matching it's size: the GMail app auto-resizes your tables to fit the screen size and it causes issues.

iOS: make sure your phone numbers and addresses are wrapped in a span that corrects for apple's auto-linking features: https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices. Also make sure you have `-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;` applied to all of your text.